# Extracting Boundary information from a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, qgis

I'm using shapefiles for the first time, and I'm trying to create a database with the boundaries of each polygon in it. So far, using qgis and the .dbf file, I have been unable to figure out how to do this. Is there a way to get the boundaries from a shapefile?

I am using the zip code shapefile from the Census Bureau. Here is a link.
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html

Thanks

Comment: For boundaries, did you mean [boundary box](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box)?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to extract the gps coordinates of each corner of the polygons that represent the zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

For boundary box, you can do it through PyQGIS or QGUIS GUI. Remember that boundary box is the minimum rectangle that evolves the geometry, so it's made by 4 coordinates:

```python
c1 = [x_min, y_min]
c2 = [x_min, y_max]
c3 = [x_max, y_min]
c4 = [x_max, y_max]
```

So you need `x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max` to construct these coordinates. I'll post the PyQGIS answer first (we are in StackOverflow) for extracting this 4 values:

```python
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

# Import layer
layer = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/cb_2016_us_zcta510_500k.shp','census_boundaries','ogr')

if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

# add to the canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# start editing
layer.startEditing()

# for field name and expression
fields = 'x_min','x_max','y_min','y_max'

for i in range(0,4):
    field = QgsField( fields[i], QVariant.Double ) # create field
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([field])
    layer.updateFields()
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(fields[i]) # extract field index
    e = QgsExpression(fields[i]+ '($geometry)' ) # use a field expression to calculate value. ie: x_min($geometry)
    e.prepare( layer.pendingFields() )
    for f in layer.getFeatures(): # fo it for all field
        f[idx] = e.evaluate( f )
        layer.updateFeature( f )


layer.commitChanges() #save changes
```

---

For QGIS GUI, simply use [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) using the same expression than the code above, creating 4 new fields (using double as data type) as:

Field 1: `x_min($geometry)`

Field 2: `x_max($geometry)`

Field 3: `y_min($geometry)`

Field 4: `y_max($geometry)`